# Svelte and TypeScript: how to add or extend a base / default component such as <div /> or <input/>

Tags: typescript, svelte

In my Svelte app I am trying to allow users to upload folders in addition to files. So far the only way I've found to do this is to use an input tag with the attribute type="file", and add the webkitdirectory attribute, which unfortunately is non-standard. The Svelte input type does not have webkitdirectory. The code works but I am getting the typescript error " Property 'webkitdirectory' does not exist on type 'SvelteInputProps'". Is it possible to extend the default types in Svelte, so I can use an input tag such as this:

```
<input
  type="file"
  multiple
  webkitdirectory  <-- attribute not accepted
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a hack but I used setAttribute as follows:

```
function setAttributeWebkitdirectory(node) {
    node.setAttribute('webkitdirectory', '');
}
```

html:

```
<input
    type="file"
    use:setAttributeWebkitdirectory
/>
```